# Deserializing the json without using jObject

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I need to deserialize my json and I should not be using jobject class in here. I tried using NewtonSoft Deserialize but I am unsuccessful in getting the desired result. I am getting null value always. Below is the code which works fine with jObject parsing. Please let me know how should I deserialize without using jObject.

code with jObject

```
public DataClassifier GetCsvSchema1()
        {
            Uri schemaPath = new Uri("https://text.z16.web.core.windows.net/");
            var schemaUri = new Uri(schemaPath, "DataFileCsvConfig.json");            
            using var client = new WebClient();
            var json = client.DownloadString(schemaUri);
            var schemajson = JsonSchema.FromJsonAsync(json);
            var root = JObject.Parse(json);
            var guestValues = root["DataClassifier"]["Classes"].ToObject<List<DataClass>>();
            DataClassifierSettings gfd = new DataClassifierSettings();
            gfd.Classes = guestValues;
            DataClassifier dsc = new DataClassifier(gfd);
            return dsc;
        }
```

the json I get in line 4 is of below sample:

```
{
  "DataClassifier": {
    "Classes": [
      {
        "Type": "Dput",
        "SubType": "VitalSigns",
        "Format": "csv",
        "DataFileIncludePatterns": [
          "**/italsigns*.csv"
        ],
        "TableSchema": {
          "Fields": [
            {
              "Name": "Time",
              "Type": "DateTime",
              "Source": [
                "TimeStamp"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "FrameCounter",
              "Type": "int"
            },
            {
              "Name": "State",
              "Type": "int"
            },
            {
              "Name": "RPM",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "Distance",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "RespirationConfidence",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "HeartBPM",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "HeartDistance",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "HeartConfidence",
              "Type": "double"
            },
            {
              "Name": "MovementPowerSlow",
              "Type": "double",
              "Source": [
                "MovementPowerSlow",
                "movement_power_slow"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "MovementPowerFast",
              "Type": "double",
              "Source": [
                "MovementPowerFast",
                "movement_power_fast"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "MovementPowerStart",
              "Type": "double",
              "Source": [
                "MovementPowerStart",
                "movement_power_start"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Name": "MovementPowerEnd",
              "Type": "double",
              "Source": [
                "MovementPowerEnd",
                "movement_power_end"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "Type": "Dtput",
        "SubType": "tage",
        "Format": "csv",
        "DataFileIncludePatterns": [
          "**/leepste*.csv"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "utput",
        "SubType": sence",
        "Format": "csv",
        "DataFileIncludePatterns": [
          "**/sence*.csv"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Type": "PSG",
        "SubType": "Type1",
        "DataSetIncludePatterns": [
          "PSG"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

the classes defined are as follows:

```
public class DataClassifierSettings
    {
        public List<DataClass> Classes { get; set; }
    }
 public class DataClass
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string SubType { get; set; }
        public string Format { get; set; }

        public List<string> DataFileIncludePatterns { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> DataFileExcludePatterns { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> DataSetIncludePatterns { get; set; } = new List<string>();
        public List<string> DataSetExcludePatterns { get; set; } = new List<string>();

        public TableSchema TableSchema { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IDataClassifier
    {
        IEnumerable<DataClass> Classes { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `NewtonSoft Deserialize but I am unsuccessful in getting the desired result.` what does that mean? JSON.NET works. You don't need JObject. If your code failed, there's a bug in the code, not the library. Post your code

Comment: He is using wrong model for given json... He asked similar question yesterday

Comment: thats right yesterday i posted the code, and there is no error, i just get null values

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916752/getting-null-element-during-deserialization?noredirect=1#comment114771593_64916752

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user has previously asked the exact same thing at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64916752/getting-null-element-during-deserialization

Comment: If you don't want to use JObject,you can create a class `public class DataClassifierSettings1 {
    public DataClassifierSettings DataClassifier { get; set; }`,and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClassifierSettings1>(json);`,Because your json shows an object have a DataClassifier(which is a model DataClassifierSettings)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
DataClassifierSettings1 dataClassifierSettings1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataClassifierSettings1>(json);
```

And here are the classes:

```
public class DataClassifierSettings1 {
    public DataClassifierSettings DataClassifier { get; set; }
}
public class TableSchema { 
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }
    public class Field {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<string> Source { get; set; }

    }
```